# pi 3 boots to display no usb keyboard or mouse

Tags: pi-3, usb, keyboard, mouse

Sorry if this is a dumb question.
I am trying to get my Pi 3 working, it is an old one and I am sure that it has been working in the past with OSMC.
My laptop is running mint 19.1, I used Etcher to create the sd, which worked fine with my Pi 1. 
The Pi 3 boots OK from the new sd card, until it asks for input, neither the keyboard (caps lock does not change state) or mouse work. I tried a wireless mouse and can see the sender wake up, so power is available at the USB ports.
Hours of web searching have not helped.
Any advice will be appreciated.

I also tried the latest Raspbian image, same result.

Thanks

Dave

Comment: try connecting the pi to the network (ethernet cable) and then use ssh - add an empty file called `ssh` in the boot partition to enable ssh - then at least you'll be able to see any errors in `dmesg` or other `log` files that may help determine the problem - I gather you've tried all four USB ports for the keyboard

Comment: If you can't connect it via Ethernet, use wifi - read on how to set up `wpa_supplicant` in boot partition for "headless" configurations

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried all the USB ports. I have no network here (on my boat) And no ethernet port on my laptop, I connect to the web with my phone hotspot. So I am very limited. Is there a way to edit the SD card to log the errors?

Comment: `My laptop is running mint 19.1` - you should be able to mount the second partition and look in `var/log` folder of that partition

Comment: not sure how phone hotspots work - if two devices use the hotspot, can they talk to each other?

Comment: I have a TPlink travelling hotspot device, in client mode it can be used as a wifi adaptor. I have tested it on my pi 1, it works and I can open a ssh terminal on it from my laptop. I then took the sd card and booted the pi 3 with it. The configuration did not pass across the connection too the tplink device.

Comment: Struggling to discover how to pre-configure the SD card so that I can make the Pi 3 connect to the hotspot. All the help I have found assumes that you can configure from the Pi end.

Comment: https://desertbot.io/blog/headless-raspberry-pi-3-bplus-ssh-wifi-setup